# How to disable automatic zoom on scale change in Android's webview?

Tags: android, webview

I've got a webview with following settings:

```
    WebSettings s = getSettings();
    s.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    s.setSupportZoom(false);
    s.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    s.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    s.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    s.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    s.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    s.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

In my app, I allow the user to change between two modes of the page which is displayed: fit screen & zoomed.
To do that, I change the scale of the page using javascript.
It all worked great, but a new requirement came along: always allow the user to use pinch to zoom, nevermind the mode they view the page with.

So I have changed these two settings:

```
    s.setSupportZoom(true);
    s.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

And voila, the user can use pinch to zoom.

Now, I have two places where I scale the page:

- javascript where I change the content scale
- java where I allow user to zoom in on the webview

This means, that when user switches to fit screen mode, I have to zoom out the webview. It took me a moment to figure out, since there's only `zoomOut()` method, which zooms out "a little bit", but fortunately it returns a boolean to indicate success or failure, so a simple:

```
while(webview.zoomOut()) {}
```

does the trick. The webpage is properly zoomed out and scaled.

There is, however, a VERY frustrating side effect: when changing to the fit screen mode, the webview suddenly zooms in a little bit. It is done with animation and lasts for about 500ms. It's done automatically, I don't have any code which would do that.

So the effect is: page zooms out to fit the screen immediately and zooms in by a little margin within 500ms.

I have removed my `zoomOut` code and didn't use the pinch to zoom in my tests, but the webview would still zoom in a bit after I change the content scale inside javascript.

The only way to remove this effect is to `setSupportZoom(false)` which disables pinch to zoom.

Did anyone came across a similar issue and know how to disable this automatic zoom in?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
s.setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.MEDIUM);
```

try this !!

Comment: @dharam this method was obsoleted long time ago.